# Mensagem errada em webservice integrando com ActionScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-service, actionscript-3

Estou fazendo uma aplicação *restful* em C#, na qual eu irei receber uma requisição via post e irei retornar um JSON ou uma *string* para o solicitante.

```
[HttpPost]
    public string confirmahora()
    {         
        String OUTPUT = "mensagem";

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);   

        return resposta;
    }
```

Porém quando a aplicação em Flash (ActionScript) recebe o seguinte cabeçalho:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">"mensagem"</string>
```

Teria que vir somente a palavra "mensagem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de devolver a resposta, certifique-se de que o cabeçalho de resposta irá devolver `text/plain`, assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public string confirmahora()
{         
    String OUTPUT = "mensagem";

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";

    return resposta;
}
```